# generating a grid with for-loops and n-variables

Tags: java, math, datagrid

i want a list of numbers like the following example:
[List of Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4NAZ.png)
The steps will be 0.2 and the sum of all the lines is always 1.

For the n=2 case it's no Problem, but if i want add a third variable (k) i get some Problems.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(double i=1.0;i>=0;i=i-0.2){
        i = Math.round(100.0 * i) / 100.0;
        for(double j=1-i;j<=1.0;j=j+0.2){
            j = Math.round(100.0*j) /100.0;
            if(i+j==1){
                System.out.println(i+"\t"+j);
            }
            if(i+j<1){
                for(double k =1-j-i;k<=1;k=k+.2){
                    k = Math.round(100.0*k)/100.0;
                    }
                }               
        }
    }
}
```

For the example i get the following result:

- 1.0  0.0
- 0.8  0.2
- 0.6  0.4
- 0.4  0.6
- 0.2  0.8
- 0.0  1.0

i will be glad if someone can help to solve my problem.

Comment: Do not confuse Java and JavaScript. 2 very different things.

Comment: What do you mean with "some problems"? Can you be more specific? What is the output you're getting? Are you getting exceptions?

Comment: I want to write a script, thats generate me a grid like at the picture for 3 or more variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `j` to `1-i` (or more).

So `i+j` evaluates to `1+(1-i)` (or more).

`i` is always less than or equal to `1` so `i+j` is always >= `1+(1-1)` = `1`.

So `if(i+j<1)` never evaluates to `true`.

So the `k` loop is never initiated.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your variables? I get the feeling you're trying to solve a fairly simple problem in a very complicated way.

I suspect you're looking for something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int d1 = 0; d1 <= 10; d1++) {
        for (int d2 = 0; d2 <= 10; d2++) {
            for (int d3 = 0; d3 <= 10; d3++) {
                if (d1 + d2 + d3 == 10) {
                    System.out.println("" + d1/10d + "  " + d2/10d + "  " + d3/10d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0.0  0.0  1.0
0.0  0.1  0.9
0.0  0.2  0.8
0.0  0.3  0.7
0.0  0.4  0.6
...
```

But looking more closely on your example, I now think **this is what you are looking for**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int d3 = 10; d3 >= 0; d3--) {
        for (int d2 = 10 - d3; d2 >= 0; d2--) {
            int d1 = 10 - d2 - d3;
            System.out.println(d1/10d + "  " + d2/10d + "  " + d3/10d);
        }
    }
}
```

It prints exactly the same items as in your example. But in a different order. Imo, my order is better. It also performs better using only two loops.

Comment: I know that the third loop with k never initiated. Do you had a look at the picture? i want to build a grid like there for 3 ore more variables.

Comment: Cool! Take a look at yet another update of my answer :)